# Kafka JMS Source Connector write message to more topics

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, apache-kafka-connect, activemq-artemis

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis JMS queue and there is a Kafka Source Connector. I want to write message from this queue to *multiple* topics parallel. I found that the Simple Message Transform could be the solution. I tried to configure `RegexRouter`, but I can only change the name of the topic?

I tried to create 3 connector instances but only one can receive message. I guess because message is deleted from queue at the first read.

Comment: You could probably solve this by using a [composite divert](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html#composite-divert) on ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: @JustinBertram I can't modify the Artemis config I'd prefer a solution in Kafka Source Connector